# 95% confidence interval for log odds

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, variance, odds

I'm looking at data from the O-Ring Challenger disaster and wasn't sure how to get a 95% confidence interval for a particular estimated log odds.[image]

In this case, I'm considering a logistic regression model where a success was an O-Ring failure. If I wanted the estimated log odds of a particular O-ring failing at a takeoff temperature of 60 degrees, I know that it would be

$x'\beta=$
  $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 60
  \end{bmatrix} $
$\begin{bmatrix}
    5.085 \\
    -0.1156 
  \end{bmatrix}$
  = -1.851

However, if I want a 95% confidence interval for these odds, should I be looking at the 95% confidence limits for intercept and temp in the table and choosing the values to maximise and minimise those odds or should I be considering something along the lines of

-1.851 $\pm$ 1.96 $\sqrt{Var(intercept)+3600Var(temp)}$?

Comment: Your formula neglects the covariance between the estimates of `Intercept` and `temp`.  If you are measuring temperature on any standard scale such as Fahrenheit or Celsius, that covariance may be appreciable and therefore you'll need its estimate as well.

Comment: You also need the covariance term: $Var(a + b x) = Var(a) + x^2 \cdot Var(b) + 1 \cdot x \cdot Cov(a,b)$.